# Column in table not exist (spring boot jpa, unidirectional OneToMany)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I develop a browser game on spring boot and I need a unidirectional OneToMany mapping. I have inventories entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "inventories")
public class Inventory {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Equipment.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "equipment_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Equipment> equipments;

    public static Inventory getDefaultInventory(String id){

        return Inventory.builder()
                .id(id)
                .equipments(new ArrayList<>())
                .build();
    }
}
```

and Equipment entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "equipments")
public class Equipment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EquipmentType type;

    private Integer strength;

    private Integer endurance;

    private Integer agility;

    private Integer intuition;

    private Integer reaction;

    private Integer rage;

    private Integer wisdom;
}
```

All one-to-one mappings work fine and empty entities saves ok.
When I am trying to put Equipment into inventory and try to save data I catch 500 error.

2021-02-27 17:44:08.548 ERROR 11108 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column equipments5_.equipment_id not exist.

Why hibernate think that eqipment_id is the Equipment column?

Comment: Do you have a column named `equipment_id` present on table `inventories`?

Comment: yeap.  from my flyway sql file:

create table inventories
(
    id varchar(64),
    equipment_id integer
);

Comment: Can you share the properties file and also other classes like `repository`?

Comment: Can you share also the code snippet (method) on the part that you are adding equipment to inventory then saving it? Thanks